# Como colocar imágenes mediante el uso de condicionales en flutter

Tags: flutter, pdf

Estoy creando un pdf desde flutter, donde mediante condicionales debo de agregar una imagen (logo), lo hago de la siguiente manera para declarar las imagenes:

```
  final imageLogo1 = MemoryImage(
      (await rootBundle.load('assets/images/1.png')).buffer.asUint8List());
  final imageLogo2 = MemoryImage(
      (await rootBundle.load('assets/images/2.png')).buffer.asUint8List());
  final imageLogo3 = MemoryImage(
      (await rootBundle.load('assets/images/3.png')).buffer.asUint8List());
```

En donde la deseo agregar lo hago de la forma siguiente:

```
SizedBox(
        height: 150,
        width: 150,
        child: Image(rsp.sociedad == '1'
                    ? imageLogo1
                    : rsp.sociedad == '2'
                    ? imageLogo2
                    : imageLogo3 ),
 )
```

Pero al tratar de revisar el pdf, siempre coloca el logo 3, aunque revisando en la comprobación tenga por ejemplo el número 1, y no se como solucionarlo.

Comment: usa un print('rsp.sociedad: ${rsp.sociedad}');  para ver que valor retorna rsp.sociedad, quizás siempre es diferente de 1 y 2

Comment: Lo que pasaba es que en la variable, no se porque siempre agregaba un espacio en blanco le puse `rsp.sociedad.trim() == 1 ....`  y solvento el problema y ahora si asigna la imagen de acuerdo a la validación. muchas gracias por contestar!